# set up Multiple clusters in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to set up two different clusters(cluster1,cluster2) of elastic search pointing same data location (UNCpath).

Cluster1 will have one master and data node
Cluster2 will also have one mater and data node.

Both Cluster1 and cluster2 will point to same data location on an UNC path.

I would like to use cluster1 only to handle index data request and cluster2 only to handle search request .

Can above set up be possible in elastic search?If yes, will it create any problem or issues having 2 different clusters pointing same data location.

The reason for this set up is because while indexing it consumes more memory and parallel user makes search request which slows down both indexing and search request.

I have 15gb ram with 16 cores and data is round about 10 million

Answer (score 0):

A weird thought, but probably you can setup an NFS for your data folder , now launch two isolated clusters with the same cluster name . By isolation I mean they should not join and become one cluster. Then use one cluster for indexing another for search.

Comment: Thanks!!.You mean to say above set up is possible with no issues?

Comment: No, this won't work. A data node doesn't consist exclusively of the data directory. There is a whole lot of index data in memory, which obviously wouldn't be shared between the nodes of your two clusters. The solution to your issue is to scale up your single cluster.

Comment: remember how before snapshot was introduced elasticsearch backups were done using disk snapshots , accepted the data in translog will not be available immediately but  after it has been flushed to disk it will possible to search on it .

Comment: though I do agree it will better if the cluster would be scaled , even if I would do it will be experimental in nature